# Convert Symfony User to array

Tags: php, json, symfony, serialization, doctrine

I have User entity which has country field as many to one reference:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Country")
 */
private $country;

/**
 * Set country
 *
 * @param string $country
 * @return User
 */
public function setCountry($country)
{
    $this->country = $country;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get country
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getCountry()
{
    return $this->country;
}
```

I need current user to be represented as array, so in controller I get current user as `$user = $this->getUser();` and use JMSSerializer and json_decode to convert object to array:

```
$userJSON = $serializer->serialize($user, 'json');
$user = json_decode($userJSON, true);
```

Now I have user object as an array, but instead of having country just as ID I get entire country object. What is the correct way to get country as ID in user object?

Comment: Have you tried to define an accessor? http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/annotations#accessor

Answer (score 0):

You have to use getter annotation for that purpose:

```
/** @Accessor(getter="getCountryName") */
private $country;

public function getCountryName()
{
    return $this->country->getName(); // or which property for country entity is used to take its name
}
```

And do not forget to add JMS Annotations in use:

```
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\Accessor;
```

Good luck.